# Python Apply function across a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

```
Function = sqrt( AB x BA )  

  A B C D    
A 1 2 3 4  
B 1 2 3 4  
C 1 2 3 4   
D 1 2 3 4

AB = 2 

BA = 1

sqrt(2 x 1)
```

apply that to all cells in dataframe

Comment: It is unclear to me what you expect. Can you try to use standard Python terminology/real python syntax?

Comment: Can you show a list that you would like to run on. I mean after AB x BA. What would you like to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for a function to get sqrt from the given row and column you can use

```
def sqrt(a,b):
    return math.sqrt(df.loc[a[0],a[1]]*df.loc[b[0],b[1]])

sqrt('AB','BC')

2.449489742783178
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
In [11]: df.applymap(np.sqrt)
Out[11]:
     A         B         C    D
A  1.0  1.414214  1.732051  2.0
B  1.0  1.414214  1.732051  2.0
C  1.0  1.414214  1.732051  2.0
D  1.0  1.414214  1.732051  2.0
```

Comment: Frankly, it is not clear to me at all that this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga really? seems clear to me. They want to apply the square root to every entry in the DataFrame.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "apply that to all cells in dataframe

"

Comment: The part that makes it totally unclear is `sqrt(2 x 1)`, and the whole `AB`, `BA` thing... Note, `AB` seem to be actings as coordinates... i.e. `AB = df.loc['A','B']`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, I've seen clearer questions!

Answer (score 0):

For a given input like this:

```
l = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]])
```

you can do something like this:

```
for i,v in l.iterrows():
     for j in range(len(v)):
        l[i][j] = math.sqrt(l[i][j]*l[j][i])
```

better way of doing it in pandas would be:

```
for i in l.columns.values:
     for j in l.index:
        l.loc[i, j] = math.sqrt(l.loc[i, j]*l.loc[j, i])
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
>>> l
          0         1         2         3
0  1.000000  1.414214  1.732051  2.000000
1  1.189207  2.000000  2.449490  2.828427
2  1.316074  2.213364  3.000000  3.464102
3  1.414214  2.378414  3.223710  4.000000
```